# Why is there white space between the elements in my <div> container?

Tags: html, html-table, html-email

I'm very new to HTML, and I've built a custom HTML email signature. I want it to look like this:

[image]

However, with my code below, the three strings I'm grouping next to each other end up with white space between the first and subsequent strings as shown below

[image]

What is a proper way to group the three strings together without getting a gap between elements?

```
<div class="presentational-container">
  <table role="presentation" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0"style="background: none;margin: 0;padding: 10px 10px 0;border-width: 1px 0 0 0;border-style: solid;border-color: #F2F2F2;">
    <tbody>
      <tr class="outer-row" style="padding: 0 12px 0 0;">
        <td class="headshot-cell" style="text-decoration: none;vertical-align: middle;width: 72px;padding: 0 6px 0 0;">
          <a href="http://www.robertcooper.me">
            <img src="https://tetonsports.imagerelay.com/ql/6cde221aa42c4ec8b325b3c0f6235d2e/email-icon-01.png" name="preview-image-url" style="vertical-align: middle;width:72px"/>
          </a>
        </td>
        <td class="description-cell">
          <table role="presentation">
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td colspan="2" class="company" style="font-weight: normal;color: #000001;font-size: 14px;font-family: Helvetica, Geneva, sans-serif;">TETON Sports</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <div>
                  <td colspan="2" class="name" style="font-weight: bold;color: #000001;font-size: 14px;font-family: Helvetica, Geneva, sans-serif;">Josh Jorgensen</td>
                  <td colspan="2" class="divider" style="font-weight: bold;color: #FF9E18;font-size: 14px;font-family: Helvetica, Geneva, sans-serif;">//</td>
                  <td colspan="2" class="title" style="font-style: italic;font-weight: normal;color: #54565A;font-size: 14px;font-family: Helvetica, Geneva, sans-serif;">Photographer</td>
                </div>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td valign="top" class="website" style="font-style: italic;font-weight: normal;color: #54565A;font-size: 14px;font-family: Helvetica, Geneva, sans-serif;">
                  <a href="josh@tetonsports.com">josh@tetonsports.com</a>
                </td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: It's not whitespace, it's just that the "comment" is in the adjacent column. I'd probably make it where that whole text string is a single `td` column, and maybe use `span` to style the text individually

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those three text parts are in separate table cells, and these tablecells even have `colspan="2"`. So these are aligned with the table cells of the rows above and below which also have `colspan="2"`.

I would either put all three in *one* cell, or at least remove the `colspan="2"` from them and add `colspan="3"` to the cells below and above, since all rows should have the same amount of cells for lining up properly.